# Mongoose sort and get non repeated values

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im new in all NodeJS/MongoDB/Mongoose tecnologies, and im trying to get non repeated values from an array, and im sorting the data by two values; **location** and **created_at**.

This is the code

```
Temperature.find().sort({'location': -1,'created_at': -1}).exec(function(err, results){
  res.json(results);
});
```

How can i get the first non repeated value from the array?

This is the array:

```
[ { 
    temperature: '24',
    humidity: '15',
    location: 'Camara4',
    created_at: 2017-01-24T21:40:21.552Z
   },
  { 
    temperature: '23',
    humidity: '15',
    location: 'Camara4',
    created_at: 2017-01-24T01:18:26.328Z
     },
  { 
    temperature: '15',
    humidity: '12',
    location: 'Camara3',
    created_at: 2017-01-26T18:53:34.447Z,
     },
  { 
    temperature: '36',
    humidity: '11',
    location: 'Camara3',
    created_at: 2017-01-24T21:41:07.094Z,
    },
  { 
    temperature: '35',
    humidity: '11',
    location: 'Camara3',
    created_at: 2017-01-24T21:41:03.092Z,
   }
]
```

and i expect:

```
[ { 
    temperature: '24',
    humidity: '15',
    location: 'Camara4',
    created_at: 2017-01-24T21:40:21.552Z
   },
  { 
    temperature: '15',
    humidity: '12',
    location: 'Camara3',
    created_at: 2017-01-26T18:53:34.447Z,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use aggregation framework.

`$group` on `location` key with `$first` operator to pick the first value from the sorted order in each group.

```
Temperature.aggregate({
    "$sort": {
        'location': -1,
        'created_at': -1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$location",
        "result": {
            "$first": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
}).exec(function(err, results) {
    res.json(results);
});
```

Output:

```
{
        "_id" : "Camara4",
        "result" : {
                "temperature" : "24",
                "humidity" : "15",
                "location" : "Camara4",
                "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-24T21:40:21.552Z")
        }
}
{
        "_id" : "Camara3",
        "result" : {
                "temperature" : "15",
                "humidity" : "12",
                "location" : "Camara3",
                "created_at" : ISODate("2017-01-26T18:53:34.447Z")
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explication and the example!

Comment: Did the query not work the way you expected ? Let me know

Comment: The query isn't sorting.

Comment: Added the output. The output matches your expected output. Your `created_at` needs to be of type `date` not `string`. That is the only thing I can see that would mess up the sorting.